# NSURL, URL and NSData, Data

Tags: swift, url, nsurl

I'm new to Swift. I was pulling an image from the Internet when I came across `NSURL` and `URL` and `NSData` and `Data`. I'm really confused. Which ones do I use? I used the following code, but I had to convert the types as shown below. What is the proper way of doing this and what is the difference between `NSURL` and `URL` and `NSData` and `Data`? Somebody please help.

```
if let theProfileImageUrl = tweet.user.profileImageURL{
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: theProfileImageUrl as URL){
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Many class names dropped the `NS` prefix with the release of Swift 3. They should only be used with Objective-C code. If you are writing Swift 3 code you should use only the updated classes. In this case, `URL` and `Data`.

However, `URL` is bridged to `NSURL` and `Data` is bridged to `NSData` so you can cast between them when needed.

```
if let theProfileImageUrl = tweet.user.profileImageURL {
    do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: theProfileImageUrl as URL)
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I don't know where `tweet.user.profileImageURL` is defined but it appears to be using `NSURL` so you need to cast it to `URL` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I converted everything to Url and Data, but I got an error on this line: if let imageData = Data(contentsOf: theProfileImageUrl){

Comment: It says "Can call throw, but is not marked with try". I feel like I'm doing something wrong. I don't think the initializer should throw an error.

Comment: I forgot about the fact that `Data(contentsOf:)` can throw an error. See my updated answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue and/or up vote questions that were helpful.

Comment: I mentioned it because I noticed you had never accepted any answer to any of your previous questions. You should go back and accept answers that actually solved any of your previous questions.

Comment: @NikhilSridhar If profileImageURL it is already an URL there is no need to cast from URL to URL. If theProfileImageUrl is NSURL just change its type declaration from NSURL  to URL. You should use only URL in Swift 3. just drop the NS prefix

Comment: @LeoDabus I was going under the assumption that `profileImageURL` is from some API that defines it as `NSURL`. You are correct, if it already `URL` then the cast isn't needed and if the OP declared it their own code to be `NSURL` then `URL` should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT 5.0 + fetch on background

```
private func fetchImage(_ photoURL: URL?) {

    guard let imageURL = photoURL else { return  }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do{
            let imageData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.userImageView.image = image
                self.userImageView.sizeToFit()
            }
        }catch{
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```