# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'setImageWith'

Tags: ios, swift

My code won't Compile, setImageWith requests the image to load in the background, or asynchronously. But i am having this compiling error. Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'setImageWith'

```
manager.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/",
                parameters: searchParameters,
                progress: nil,
                success: { (operation: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject:Any?) in
                    if let responseObject = responseObject as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print("Response: " + (responseObject as AnyObject).description)
                       if let photos = responseObject["photos"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let photoArray = photos["photo"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 320 * CGFloat(photoArray.count))
                            for (i,photoDictionary) in photoArray.enumerated() {                             //1
                            if let imageURLString = photoDictionary["url_m"] as? String {               //2
                                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:320*CGFloat(i), width:320, height:320))     //#1
                                if let url = URL(string: imageURLString) {
                                    imageView.setImageWith(url)                                             //#2
                                    self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
                                                                 //6
                                }
                               }
                             }
                           }
                        }
                    }


    })
```

Comment: "Width", not "With"?

Comment: You will have hard time to compile, setImageWith doesn't exist https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview. Anyway you may check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40812523/2450755 and remember to assign the image inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: setImageWith is not Default function being provided I think, You need to create a separate extension function for this

Comment: setImageWith is part of the AFNetworking library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. The `UIImageView` class does not have a method `setImageWith(_:)`.

You say "...setImageWith requests the image to load in the background, or asynchronously." What makes you think such a method exists?

Is it part of some third party extension to UIImageView that your'e trying to use or something? Are you basing this on somebody else's code?